# #inlcude errors detected. Please update your includePath eosio

Tags: configure, eos

I am learning eosio smart contracts and in the beginning of the tutorial, they ask for me to include eosio/eosio.hpp. however, because of my CDT version, it is eosiolib. I am using vscode 2019 on a mac. After I finish typing I get an error that says: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. 
Here is my .json file

````
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/local/include",

                "${workspaceFolder}/**"

            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-9",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ]
            },
            "cppStandard": "c++11"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the path to your eosio.cdt include directories.
Here is an [article](https://cmichel.io/eosio-c-intelli-sense-in-vs-code/) with more info, but the following should fix your problems.

```
"includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/opt/eosio.cdt/opt/eosio.cdt/include/**
        ],
        "defines": [
            "uint128_t=__uint128_t",
            "int128_t=__int128_t"
        ]
```

Also, update cppStandard to `"cppStandard": "c++17"`
(Version of the C++ language standard to use for IntelliSense). EOS smart contracts are written in C++17.

Answer (score 0):

2 years old, but I came across this issue with `eosio.cdt 1.8.1` and VSCode giving me "squiggles" when including `.hpp` files, namely `eosio/eosio.hpp`.

1. Installed via brew `brew tap eosio/eosio.cdt` and `brew install eosio.cdt`
2. Symlinked a portion of the repo `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.8.1/opt/eosio.cdt eosio`
3. Updated the `includePath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` to the following:

```
"includePath": [
    "/usr/local/include/eosio/**",
    "/usr/local/include/eosio/1.8.1/opt/eosio.cdt/include/**",
    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
],
```

I had to add that additional line `/usr/local/include/eosio/1.8.1/opt/eosio.cdt/include/**` since vscode kept giving me an error saying it couldn't find the `bluegrass/meta/refl.hpp` file. I'm guessing there's some recursive folder search issue I missed with this approach.

Funny enough, I was able to merely add `/usr/local/**` to the `includePath` and vscode found everything, but I imagine that's a more costly search.